# How to set Proxy in Karate Framework

Tags: karate, intuit-partner-platform

I am trying to hit an API using IP port. But the Machine is behind a VPN. Even though my local is connected to the VPN, the HTTP connection is refused. Is there any provision to setup up VPN/Proxy in Karate Framework?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Please refer to the documentation: https://github.com/intuit/karate#managing-headers-ssl-timeouts-and-http-proxy